# T-SQL Project Table + Mapping Transforms -> New Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, user-defined-functions, unpivot

I want to produce the most performant way of doing the following...

I have a source table [products]

```
ColA | ColB | ColC

  AA |  B   |  CD

  AA |  E   |  CD
```

And a mapping specification table [mappings]

```
TargetField | MatchExpr | ValueExpr
     ColA   |   AA      |    ZZ
     ColA   |   ZZ      |    BB
     ColC   |   CD      |     F
```

Extra points-- it could also specify a ValueFields Column with a Value such as 
'ColB, ColC' and a ValueExpr such as '{0} - {1}' for which a FORMAT must  be applied to get the true ValueExpr.

I'm  trying to produce a table valued function

```
CREATE FUNCTION RuleMappedProducts()
    RETURNS @MPROD TABLE 
    (ColA, ColB, ColC)
    AS
BEGIN
    -- Fill the table variable with the rows for the result set

    RETURN 
END
GO
```

I was thinking of pivoting the Mapping table to prepare it for cross joining, but the lack of numeric aggregates has me confused.

I would like to produce a result table with the mappings applied to the columns in the order specified by the mapping table. The column specified in the mapping table entry will be updated with the ValueExpr if the MatchExpr matches.
Therefore the result would be

```
    ColA | ColB | ColC |  
     BB  |  B   |    F  
     BB  |  E   |    F
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Kindly post the expected result.

Comment: Kindly edit your question and put the expected result.